# Create git patch per changed file in a branch

Tags: git, git-branch, patch, git-diff

I want create a list of patches where each patch contains the changes for that particular file in the branch against the "up-stream" (to the time where I create the branch from the up-stream) ... I want see a list like this:

```
changed-file-foo.java.patch
changed-path__file-foo.java.patch
changed-path_subpath_file-foo.java.patch
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using bash, do:

`for f in $(find . ! -path "./.git/*"); do git diff branch1 branch2 -- $f > $f.patch; done`

It goes through all files of your current directory except `/.git/` that is not useful for creating patches